# My Bootstrap Modal is Not hiding after Successful Login,Got Stuck

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I got stuck at this javascript code,why it is not working ,I used a static backdrop bootstrap model for login,after successful login ,i want to hide the model in success callback function but the model is not hiding,the Page is still there,don't know what i am doing wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m80j5.png)

Myjs File

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',

    });


});


function Login() {

    var dataobject = { Social_Security_Number: $('#Social_Security_Number').val(), Lumik_Id: $('#Lumik_Id').val() };
   // var dataobject = { Social_Security_Number:"123456789", Lumik_Id: "sgupta8" };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/Login',
        type: "POST",
        data: dataobject,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {


            if (result.toString == "Success") {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');

               //redirecttoPage()
            }



        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Error');

        }


    })


}
```

UserController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using login.Models;

namespace login.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        UserBusinessLogic obj = new UserBusinessLogic(); 

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Login(User user)
        {
            string message = "";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (obj.checkuserlogin(user) > 0)
                {
                    message = "Success";
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Username or Password is wrong"; 
                }
            }
            else {
                message = "ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED";
            }

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                // return RedirectToAction("Profile", "User", new { @name = result });

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
        }

        public ActionResult Profile(string name)
        {


            return View();

        }

    }
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

</head>
@*<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>*@
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Myfile.js"></script>
    <link href="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<body>
     @RenderBody()
</body>
```

Login.cshtml

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-header">

                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for ="Social_Security_Number" class="col-lg-3 control-label"></label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="Social_Security_Number" placeholder="Social Security Number" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Lumik_Id" class="col-lg-3 control-label"></label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="Lumik_Id" placeholder="Lumik Id" type="text" />

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Login()" />

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>

    .modal-dialog {
    max-width:480px;
    }

    .modal-dialog {
    transform:translate(0,58%) !important;
    -as-transform:translate(0,58%) !important;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,58%) !important;

    }

    .RbtnMargin {
    margin-left:90px;
    }


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try : `$(document).find('#myModal').modal('hide');` instead of `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`
Reason is : your data added dynamically. 
Let me know.

Comment: i am not able to show any alert also on success callback ,on debugging i could see control is going to callback with success but after that nothing is happeneing